# Running python 2 from python 3 using a Wrapper

Tags: python, wrapper

I have an application which is written in Python 3 but one specific functionality I need is TELAPI (https://github.com/TelAPI/telapi-python/) which is only available for Python 2.

Is it possible that I can put my Python 2 code in a wrapper and invoke it from Python 3?

Comment: Not really. You could, however, try *porting* the code to Python 3.

Comment: what you are doing is self contained(or could be made that way) you could always use subprocess and stdin/stdout to communicate with python2. But that is ugly, porting as @jonrsharpe suggested is much better.

Comment: Have you tried automatic conversion: https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [PythonFuture](http://python-future.org/) which has a [translation package](http://python-future.org/translation.html) that allows for using Python 2 only dependencies in Python 3 code.

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ will do the job Although it is almost always better to re code in Python 3 unless you need to accommodate legacy code

Comment: I don't see how virtual environments would solve the problem of calling Python 2 code from a Python 3 program. They seem mostly unrelated to this problem. Maybe you need to explain further?